# How to get SQL output that oracle puts out in SQLDeveloper when we run same scripts using Liquibase under DeployIt?

Tags: oracle, liquibase, deployit

I am beginner to liquibase usage and also to deployIT.

My question is when we run sql statements in sql developer editor we get output like anonymous block completed and also we see output of statements dbms_output.put_line....

If we run same scripts from liquibase,deployIt it does not show whatever shown in sqldeveloper editor like **anonymous block completed** etc

can any one please suggest what all can be done ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer but strange is liquibase does not allow meta statements like SET SERVEROUTPUT ON in sql scripts..any solution you suggest please ?

Comment: Yeah, run DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE and DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES

Comment: You mean instead of putting SET SERVEROUTPUT ON in sql,Do we need add DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE; DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES; in .sql ?

Comment: liquibase doesn't know how to manage dbms_output, so you have to script it yourself...so short answer, YES